# How to print \n on a string during a child process on a fork

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, fork

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    fork();
    printf("Show me the new line before the pid child dies \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>Show me the new line before the pid child dies Show me the new line before the pid child dies"\n
>
```

My expected result would be to show the '\n' as part of the string and to have two separate lines, as below:

```
>string1 \n
>string2 \n
>
```

but I am getting the following:

```
>string1 string2 \n
>
```

I tried with the fflush(stdout) but didn't make a difference.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    fork();
    printf("Show me the new line before the pid child dies \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Same output:

```
>"Show me the new line before the pid child dies Show me the new line before the pid child dies"
>
```

How do I make it so I get the following output:

```
>"Show me the new line before the pid child dies \n"
> Show me the new line before the pid child dies \n"
>
```

---

Update:

If I run it as below, it shows me the correct lines (as I wanted):

Command on terminal / powershell

```
 .\f.exe > f.out
```

Output:

```
1 Show me the new line before the pid child dies 
2 Show me the new line before the pid child dies 
3
```

I am changing my question then: Can I actually get the exact same output shown on my terminal (vs code / powershell), as I am getting on my f.out file?

I'm running MS Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: Sorry, will do.

Comment: Also, I cannot use | cat because I am on windows environment, I'm not on linux / unix system , as when I try to do "./f | cat " I get the following error: " InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand" as Expected

Comment: Can't seem to replicate: https://rextester.com/XRA51984

Comment: Yeah good luck replicating a race condition exactly.

Comment: Jessica Pereira, Although I would not expect a difference, does `puts("xxx");` perform differently than `printf("xxx\n");` on your machine?

Comment: @chux performs the same. "fork(); puts("Show me the new line before the pid child dies");" gives: "string1 string2\n" on terminal , and string1 \n string2 \n on the file output ^^

Comment: Jessica Pereira, Does the first give "string1 string2 \n" or "string1 string2 \n\n"?  (Details on spaces and `'\n'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you got a racing condition, after the call to `fork()` both the parent thread and the child thread are trying to print simultaneously. The behavior in this case is undefined. The whole idea of homework is probably to teach you that. You should use some sort of inter thread communication, or simply wait in the parent process (or in child it does not matter).

`if (fork()) sleep(1);`

Update:

After carefully reading your output line I realised that your exercise is probably to learn to wait in the parent process until the child dies, this is achieved like this:

`if (fork() != 0) wait(NULL);`

Comment: Well, that will not result on my expected output. Instead I have the following:
>./f
>Show me the new line before the pid child dies
>Show me the new line before the pid child dies
>

So, it does it 4x now, and it waits 1 second between the first and the second "print" after the first \n (between 2nd and 3rd '>')

Comment: This is actually interesting / confusing / weird, now that I just changed the code to what you said, which is: 

if(fork()){
        sleep(1);
    }

it prints 4 times what should have be printed only 2 times...
but thanks for your answer, I am feeling like "the more I know, the more I realize I don't know" kind of vibe which is good ahha @exebook

Comment: Did you add my line or have you replaced your simple call to fork with my line? Maybe you now have two calls to `fork()` instead of one.

Comment: Nope. Only one call of fork, inside the if() block.

Comment: EXACTLY!!!!!!! @exebook YOU ARE AMAZING THANK YOU SO MUCH :) 
Can you just answer my (I know it will be a - ) dumb question xD , when you check if fork() != 0, you are checking if the fork() is not the parent, therefore if it is not the parent , It is then the child, and if it is the child then I want to wait for the child to die, is that it? (parent will be fork() == 0 )

Comment: with that update, it works both for the console (buffer stdout terminal ) and output file. Once again, thank you @exebook

Comment: In this example function `wait` is called in the parent only. Fork returns zero to a child, and a numeric ID of a child to a parent. `wait(NULL)` will wait untill all children exit. Instead you could save the returned id in a variable and then give that variable to `wait`. You could (and probably should have) read the docs for both fork and wait. Also known as mans. But I know how difficult they are to read for a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Typical concurrency problem. Enforce correct multi-threaded behavior and eliminate race conditions with mutex locks and the like.

Per POSIX and ISO, stdout buffers output until it hits a newline or explicitly flushes, which takes time and the race condition bites you. If you're redirecting to a file, std behaves differently.   The newline gets into the buffer but doesn't kick off a flush, while the explicit `fflush` will force it, so printf concludes and the children don't bump each other until the middle of `fflush` but your buffer is set up as you want by then.   You probably shouldn't depend on that timing happening like that.